# Error while inserting floating point value in textboxfor MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a strange problem, I have a model definied like this:

```
public class AddEventModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Nazwa wydarzenia")]
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Rodzaj")]
    public string EventType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Data")]
    public System.DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Widocznosc")]
    public string IsPublic { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Minimalny wiek")]
    public int MinimalAge { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Cena")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public decimal Payment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Opis")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Miasto")]
    public string City { get; set; }


    public SelectList EventTypeList { get; set; }
}
```

What is more i have a page writen in razor like this (i will post just part of it):

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EventName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EventName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EventType, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EventType, Model.EventTypeList, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EventDate, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EventDate, new { @class = "form-control", id = "datepicker" })
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
                        minDate: moment()
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsPublic, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsPublic, "Prywatne") Prywatne</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsPublic, "Publiczne") Publiczne</label></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MinimalAge, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MinimalAge, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Payment, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Payment, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Okay, so, when I am inserting my new event with a floating point number in field Cena/Payment im getting a strange error like this:

> The ViewData item that has the key 'EventType' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

It is pretty strange beacuse it is pointing on dropdownlist which is not connected with a Payment field. As I said, when I put a integer into Payment field - everything works fine.

Whats going on guys?

**EDIT**

Okey guys, i get it that i didnt reassing a SelectList in a post method. I fixed that already. However:

1. I want to understand why it was apearing only when i put a floating point number in a textbox
2. How to fix next problem: `Value 'x.x' is not valid for Cena`

Comment: It has nothing to do with a 'floating point'. Its because the value of `Model.EventTypeList` is `null`, probably because when you post and then return the view you have not reassigned the `SelectList` (and in future just post the minimum code necessary to reproduce the issue - all those other properties in your model and the view have nothing to do with your problem!)

Comment: @StephenMuecke okey, u was right about not reassgning the Select list. I did it, and error disapeared. However, explain me why it apears ONLY when i put an decimal number? What is more i still cant insert a decimal number cuz of error validation like: `The value '3.1' is not valid for Cena.` I have this error before and adding `<globalization culture ="en-US" />` in web.config file solved problem then

Comment: Because the culture on the server does not accept a dot as the decimal separator (probably its a comma). So when you post `3.1`, it adds a `ModelState` error (because it should have been `3,1`) and best guess is that if `ModelState` is invalid you do `return View(model);` but forgot to reassign the `SelectList`. When you entered an integer, `ModelState` was not invalid so you were probably saving and redirecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is throw because the value of `EventTypeList` in

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EventType, Model.EventTypeList, new { @class = "form-control" }
```

is `null`

This is happening because when you post back, `ModelState` is invalid and you return the view without re-assigning the `SelectList` (as you did in the GET method).

The reason `ModelState` is invalid is because the culture on the server does not accept the `.` (dot) character as a decimal separator (most likely it is a culture that uses `,` (comma) as the decimal separator). You need to change the culture in the `web.config` file, for example to `<<globalization culture ="en-US" />`